# Why dominant-baseline doesn't work when I convert svg to pdf?

Tags: pdf, svg, batik

Why `dominant-baseline` doesn't work when I convert svg to pdf using Java-based toolkit Batik. 
When I display svg in browser all ok and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batik [does not support](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/status.html) dominant-baseline

Comment: Do you know any alternative for this? How in other way I can make vertical alignment that will work in Batik?

Comment: You'd have to adjust the text manually using y or dy attributes I guess.